# When should I use ICollection<T> or IEnumerable<T> in viewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**using IEnumerable**

view model

```
public class ResumeDetailsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<WorkExperience> WorkExperiences { get; set; }
}
```

in controller

```
var workExperiences = _dbContext.WorkExperiences.Where(w => w.UserId == userId);
var viewModel = new ResumeDetailsViewModel
{
    WorkExperiences = workExperiences,
};
```

in view

```
@if (Model.WorkExperiences.Any())
{
    foreach (var workExperience in Model.WorkExperiences)
    {
        @workExperience.JobTitle
    }
}
```

**using ICollection**

view model

```
public class ResumeDetailsViewModel
{
    public ICollection<WorkExperience> WorkExperiences { get;set; }
}
```

in controller

```
var workExperiences = _dbContext.WorkExperiences.Where(w => w.UserId == userId);
var viewModel = new ResumeDetailsViewModel
{
    WorkExperiences = workExperiences.ToList()
};
```

in view

```
@if (Model.WorkExperiences.Any())
{
    foreach (var workExperience in Model.WorkExperiences)
    {
        @workExperience.JobTitle
    }
}
```

I want to have least query as possible. In my example both approach creates 2 queries `Model.WorkExperiences.Any()` and `var workExperience in Model.WorkExperience` for IEnumerable while `workExperiences.ToList()` and `Model.WorkExperiences.Any()` for ICollection.

Please correct me if I'm wrong with my assumption.

When should I use ICollection or IEnumerable?

Comment: ICollection does some things that IEnumerable doesn't. It has a `Count` property. It has Add, Remove, and Clear methods. If you need any of the features that ICollection has and IEnumerable doesn't, use ICollection.

Comment: ICollection inherits from IEnumerable and provides a few more methods and properties to allow for better access (rather than just looping through with an iterator).

Comment: You don't need your call to `.Any()` - just do your foreach.

Comment: @juharr `ICollection<T>` doesn't have an indexer; that's `IList<T>`. For example `HashSet<T>` implements `ICollection<T>`, but not `IList<T>`.

Comment: @DanField thanks for pointing it out.